# How can I use Postgres collation in Windows OS?

Tags: postgresql, collation

I want to customize ICU Collation of Postgres server in my windows machine.

so I created a new collation using:

```
CREATE COLLATION digitslast (provider = icu, locale = 'ja-u-kr-latn-digit');
```

and expected as below.

ex)

```
# select code from table order by code collate "digitslast";

code |
-----+--
a    | ...
A    | ...
1    | ...
...  | ...
```

But result has the same order as the default order.

```
code |
-----+--
1    | ...
a    | ...
A    | ...
...  | ...
```

Is this possible? And is there some mistake?

Comment: I want to emulate [EBCDIC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006820.html)

Comment: I can reproduce this with PostgreSQL v10. On Linux it works as expected, but not so on Windows. One thing I notice is that my Windows PostgreSQL uses ICU version 53, while on Linux I have 60. Perhaps an ICU bug that got fixed? But it could also be a PostgreSQL bug.

Comment: I tried to place ICU62 dlls to my PostgreSQL\bin  But it seems not working...